# What causes this question to be 'active'?

Tags: support, questions

What caused [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228539/simplest-fortran-code-still-has-an-error) question to be listed as active? When sorting for questions tagged [[fortran]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) by active, it shows as recently modified:

[image: Photo showing 'modified 6 hours ago']

However, I can't figure out what modification was made. I found a [list of causes for a question getting bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped), but as far as I can tell none of those has occured. There's no new edits, comments, or answers.

How can I reliably determine what causes questions to be 'active'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer was posted that has since been deleted.

> How can I reliably determine what causes questions to be 'active'?

Click on the text stating when it was modified and it will direct you to the post that was edited.  If it doesn't take you to any post, you know it was one that you're not able to see (meaning it was deleted).

If you mean in general, rather than on a specific question, then the answer is "in the list that you linked to".