# What makes a question 'active'?

Tags: support, statistics, last-activity

I reached an inactive question in which I downvoted an answer, engaged in a small conversation with OP and after all that the question still shows *`active yesterday`*.

Why is that?

Before flagging my question as dupe note that:

- [What is the difference between "hot" and "active" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-and-active-questions)
  Here [one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2042/271865) suggests that *Active is based on creation / last modified time of any answer or the question itself*. However, that seems like a guess to me, no official answer, and it's not in the scope of the question to ask for details
- [How do I make question active of other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125227/how-do-i-make-question-active-of-other-users)
  In here 3 things are shown as making a question active:

  - editing
  - placing a bounty (which is still editing as it affects revisions)
  - answering the question and deleting the answer
    However it's only a guess and on top of that it was flagged as dupe after:
- [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer)
  Which talks about the same things as above (editing & bounty) and is not what I'm asking
- [What causes this question to be 'active'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345043/what-causes-this-question-to-be-active)
  There's also this one which, much like the two questions above, suggests that only edits or answers will mark a question as 'active'

But I didn't find anywhere a clear, official definition as an answer for this question.
To me commenting and voting on a question is activity as well, which is why I'm suprised and am looking for an official answer.

Comment: Comments are second-class citizens and votes don't add any new content - it makes sense for those to be excluded if you think of "activity" as something new you haven't seen yet.

Comment: No, I'm not thinking of *"activity"* as  *"when's the last time something changed"*, I'm thinking of activity as *"when's the last time something **happened**"*. But thanks anyway for the first `-1`. Was looking for that with this question

Comment: But what would be the point of that? A new answer or an edit means that maybe the thread is worth checking out again. There would be little point to looking at a thread again if the only thing that changed was post score.

Comment: Why do you see a question being active as an indicative that it needs to be looked at again? Active is a word describing activity, not edits or change in content

Comment: (It's not nice to accuse people of downvoting your post. Disagreeing with part of your post, or even your whole post, doesn't automatically mean I downvoted)

Comment: Things should have purpose. Maybe it should be called something else then, but my point remains - having something that tells you whether a post might be worth checking out again seems much more useful than something that tells you when even the most inconsequential of things happened.

Comment: If your downvote dropped score of the answer from positive, it may trigger one of the known [meta-tag:bump]ing criteria: "The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that. " Consider checking revisions history of the question you ask about because if this is what happened then [there will be a message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287445/165773)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two posts on MSE that explain this.

The first post is [What is the active link for on the right side of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146959/what-is-the-active-link-for-on-the-right-side-of-a-question)

> "active" refers to question activity that may cause it to be bumped to the front page, which may be one of the following things (among [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)):
>
> - The question was posted (in which case, date active is the same as date asked)
> - An answer was posted
> - The question, or one of its answers, was edited
> - A bounty was started

The second post is linked in the quote: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)
I won't quote the content here since it could get out-of-date with the maintained answer, so just take a look at the link.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the strong correlation between that field and [the list of "active" questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKsxG.png)

Comment: Also not that active (below the viewed x times in the top right) only appears after there is atleast 1 answer.

Comment: The question was also about what defines "Hot" I think; would be a nice addition to the answer